Create JsonValue from multiple columns in Rust Polars DataFrame
I have a DataFrame with two columns in it, one an integer and one a string. For each row, I need to combine these two values into a JSON object with a certain schema ({"a": a, "b": b}). Then I need to bind a vector of these objects to an sqlx query so I can insert them into my Postgres database.
This works with just a single column:
use serde_json::json;

//...

    let cols = merged_df
        .columns(["a"])
        .unwrap();
    let values: Vec<serde_json::Value> = cols[0]
        .str()?
        .into_iter()
        .map(|a| json!({"a": a}))
        .collect();

So my questions are:

How do I draw from multiple columns when creating my JSON?
Is using map the most idiomatic way to create the final value? Is it performant? I've found other multi-column approaches which use apply or with_column, but these return new DataFrame objects, and I don't think I can have a column with a serde_json::Value object. Maybe I can use into_struct and a custom struct which I populate that implements serde_json::Serialize, but I think I'll still have to iterate through the column again somehow to serialize the struct into the serde_json::Value objects to send to sqlx. If so, iterating through twice seems inefficient.


You can just zip two columns together. If you have more than two columns, you might want itertools::izip!.
use polars::prelude::*;
use serde_json::json;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let df = df![
      "a" => [Some(1), None, Some(3)],
      "b" => [Some("x"), Some("y"), None],
    ]
    .unwrap();

    let a = df.column("a")?.i32()?;
    let b = df.column("b")?.str()?;

    let j = a
        .into_iter()
        .zip(b)
        .map(|(a, b)| json!({ "a": a, "b": b }))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{j:#?}");

    Ok(())
}

[
    Object {
        "a": Number(1),
        "b": String("x"),
    },
    Object {
        "a": Null,
        "b": String("y"),
    },
    Object {
        "a": Number(3),
        "b": Null,
    },
]

